# Multithreading in OpenEdge

Tags: multithreading, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there any concept like multithreading in OpenEdge? If so, please give me a brief about it.

I want to create a snake game in OpenEdge. For that, the user has to control the object but once the application has started, no user interaction is available there.

Comment: You don't need multithreading for "snake"

Comment: @TomBascom Maybe there are multiple snakes. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Multi-threading is not available in Progress OpenEdge so far. There are many links about this.  The following are two of them:

https://community.progress.com/community_groups/products_enhancements/i/openedge/add_support_for_multithreading_in_openedge

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P73663

Answer (score 5):

Asnyc AppServer calls is the closest you can get.